# Java - ArrayOutOfBoundsException help me

Tags: java, arrays, exception, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScoreCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int[] score = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
        System.out.println("Enter word: ");
        String word = in.nextLine();
        int totalScore = 0;
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(wordArray[i]);
            int index = Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(wordArray[i]);
            System.out.println(index);
            totalScore = totalScore + score[index];
        }
        System.out.println(totalScore);
    }
}
```

This keeps coming up with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Because it can't find any of the characters in the array alphabet can someone help plz!

Comment: what is the value of wordArray[i] when you get the error? Also make sure you are using all lower case letters.

Comment: @twain249 it comes up with the first letter that is in the word. so if i wrote in "quiz" it prints 'q'. and index prints out with -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf(wordArray[i])` is returning -1. I suspect this is due to uppercase letters and/or special characters. Do this first and add error checking:

```
word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()
```

Regardless, I would do something like this instead as it's much cleaner:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

and then

```
int index = alphabet.indexOf(wordArray[i]);
if(index == -1) {
    // handle the special character
} else {
    totalScore += score[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I would do to make this all Object Oriented and such is the following:

```
public class CharacterScore  //name this whatever makes you happy
{  
   int value;  
   char character;  

   public CharacterScore(int value, char character)  
   {  
     this.value=value;  
     this.character=character;  
   }  //getters/setters  
}
```

Then in your main program you would do something as follows:

```
private static List<CharacterScore> characterScores;  
static  
{  
   characterScores = new ArrayList<CharacterScore>();  
   String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
   for(char current : alphabet.toCharArray())  
   {  
     characterScores.add(new CharacterScore((int)Math.random() *10), current));
   }  
}
```

Now when you get user input you take the `word` convert it to a `char[]` execute some code like so:

```
for(CharacterScore current : characterScores)  
{  
    for(int i = 0; i <wordArray.length; i++)  
    {  
       if(current.getCharacter() == wordArray[i])  
       {  
             recordScore(current.getValue());  
       }  
    }  
}
```

This is not necessarily the best way to do this, but I wanted to help you understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of your problem is that argument of method `Arrays.asList` is generic vararg `(T... a)` and you are using array of primitive chars.

Solution: use object `Character[] alphabet = {'a','b', ...}` instead of primitives `char[] alphabet = {'a','b', ...}` because `T...` is not threating `char[] alphabet` as array of objects, but as one object so your list would contain only reference to that array.